# ApSS referencing style

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

After submitting a paper to springer I got this error message:

> Please revise the paper to conform with ApSS referencing style which
>   is not [n].

What does that mean?

I am using the `revtex4-1` class.

This is an example sample of my paper

```
\documentclass[% 
reprint,
amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,onecolumn,showkeys,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}



\title{Title}




\author{Name}%

\affiliation{%
Aff
}%






\date{\today}% It is always \today, today,
             %  but any date may be explicitly specified

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\begin{description}

\item[PACS numbers] 04.50.Kd, 04.20.-q, 04.25.Nx
\end{description}
\end{abstract}

\pacs{04.50.Kd, 04.20.-q, 04.25.Nx}% PACS, the Physics and Astronomy
                             % Classification Scheme.
\keywords{keywords}
\maketitle

%\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
s





\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{dolgov2003can} Dolgov, Alexander D. {\em Can modified gravity explain accelerated cosmic expansion?} 2003: Physical Review D 68 123512.

\bibitem{nojiri2003modified} Nojiri, Shin’ichi and Odintsov, Sergei D {\em Modified gravity with negative and positive powers of curvature: Unification of inflation and cosmic acceleration} 2003: Physics Letters B 573 1-4.

\bibitem{carroll2003cosmic} Carroll, Sean M and Duvvuri, Vikram and Trodden, Mark and Turner, Michael S {\em Is cosmic speed-up due to new gravitational physics?} 2003

\bibitem{thorne2000gravitation} Wheeler, Thorne, Wheeler {\em Gravitation} 2003:  636–679

\bibitem{song2007large} Song, Yong-Seon and Hu, Wayne and Sawicki, Ignacy {\em Large scale structure of $f(R)$ gravity} 2007: Physical Review D 044004

\bibitem{faulkner2007constraining} Faulkner, Thomas and Tegmark, Max and Bunn, Emory F and Mao, Yi {\em Constraining $f(R)$ gravity as a scalar-tensor theory} 2007: Physical Review D 063505

\bibitem{bean2007dynamics} Bean, Rachel and Bernat, David and Pogosian, Levon and Silvestri, Alessandra and Trodden, Mark {\em Dynamics of linear perturbations in $f(R)$ gravity} 2007: Physical Review D 064020

\bibitem{sawicki2007stability} Sawicki, Ignacy and Hu, Wayne {\em Stability of cosmological solutions in $f(R)$ models of gravity} 2007: Physical Review D 127502

\bibitem{li2007cosmology} Li, Baojiu and Barrow, John D {\em Cosmology of $f(R)$ gravity in the metric variational approach} 2007: Physical Review D 084010

\bibitem{tsujikawa2008effect} Tsujikawa, Shinji and Tatekawa, Takayuki {\em The effect of modified gravity on weak lensing} 2008: Physical Review B 325--331

\bibitem{carroll2005cosmology} Carroll, Sean M and De Felice, Antonio and Duvvuri, Vikram and Easson, Damien A and Trodden, Mark and Turner, Michael S {\em Cosmology of generalized modified gravity models} 2005: Physical Review D 063513

\bibitem{starobinsky2007disappearing} Starobinsky, Alexei A {\em Disappearing cosmological constant in $f(R)$ gravity} 2007: JETP Letters 157--163


\bibitem{saaidi2012strong} Saaidi, Kh and Vajdi, A and Rabiei, SW and Aghamohammadi, A and Sheikhahmadi, H {\em Strong and weak gravitational field in $R+{\mu^{4}}/R$ gravity} 2012: Astrophysics and Space Science 739--745

\bibitem{arbuzova2012curvature} Arbuzova, EV and Dolgov, AD and Reverberi, L {\em Curvature oscillations in modified gravity and high energy cosmic rays} 2012: Eur. Phys. J. C 2247

\bibitem{cognola2008class} Cognola, G and Elizalde, E and Nojiri, S and Odintsov, SD and Sebastiani, L and Zerbini, S {\em Class of viable modified f (R) gravities describing inflation and the onset of accelerated expansion} 2008: Physical Review D 046009

\bibitem{gannouji2009growth} Gannouji, Radouane and Moraes, Bruno and Polarski, David {\em The growth of matter perturbations in $f(R)$ models} 2009: Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics 034

\bibitem{bengochea2009dark} Bengochea, Gabriel R and Ferraro, Rafael {\em Dark torsion as the cosmic speed-up} 2009: Physical Review D 124019

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Was this an online submission?

Comment: yes, it was online

Comment: So, where are the author's guidelines for submission. There must be some reference to ApSS style in there, with an example. Could you point us in that direction? Do they specify anything in terms of BibTeX or BibLaTeX? The reason I ask is that it seems you've formatted the content *manually*, rather than using a manager like BibTeX... perhaps that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Does this help https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636

Comment: You need to spoon-feed us information. What `\documentclass` are you using? Are you using BibTeX or BibLaTeX? Are you writing a monograph or a book? What?

Comment: \documentclass[% 
reprint,
amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,onecolumn,showkeys,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-1}

Comment: No, include this as an edit to your post, since comments only have limited formatting. Also consider the community: We would have to submit a paper ourselves through the online submission system in order to be able to replicate your results... something that is most likely not going to happen. Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your results? Click on the given link, read through the contents and update the post accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: What journal is this for? Each Springer journal have specific requirements...

Comment: Astrophysics and Space Science (ASTR) Journal

Comment: I think you need to use a different setup for this to work. Without going through the process myself, I'm only providing a speculative answer. You need to use BibTeX rather than you manual setup; that will guarantee the format of the references will match their requirements, as the formatting (composition and layout) would be based on their `.bst` file.

Comment: Werner, I have done what you have kindly suggested but the editor have sent my paper back stating the same reason i.e. ApSS referencing style.

Answer (score 2):

Springer supports the use of BibTeX in terms of its references. And, since it requires journal-specific reference styles, it's best to use a reference tool like BibTeX to manage the layout to suit the submission needs.

Looking at your document template, you've created a bibliography manually. That is, you've specified a `thebibliography` environment with `\bibitem`s verbatim. Instead, you should follow these steps:

1. Download the [LaTeX Author Package for publications in ASTR journal](http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/astr.html)

   [`astr-support.zip`](http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/astr/astr-support.zip) includes a bunch of files. Specifically it includes a BibTeX style `spr-mp-nameyear-cnd.bst`.
2. Construct your references in a file `references.bib` (say) using the default BibTeX syntax that has the form

   ```
   @<type>{<bibID>,<key-value list>}
   ```

   For example, let's take one of your `\bibitem`s and rewrite it in this form:

   ```
   @article{arbuzova2012curvature,
     author  = Arbuzova, EV and Dolgov, AD and Reverberi, L,
     title   = Curvature oscillations in modified gravity and high energy cosmic rays,
     year    = 2012,
     journal = Eur.\ Phys.\ J.\ C,
     pages   = 2247
   }
   ```
3. Now, instead of a `thebibliography` environment, you should have

   ```
   \bibliographystyle{spr-mp-nameyear-cnd}
   \bibliography{references}
   ```

Of course, the above setup is completely different to what you're used to. You need to follow a compilation sequence pdfLaTeX > bibtex > pdfLaTeX > pdfLaTeX in order to test your output. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764). However, this seems to be the way that Springer requests/would accept submissions.

Comment: ok, I'll try this and see what happens

Comment: Werner, I have done what you have kindly suggested but the editor have sent my paper back stating the same reason i.e. ApSS referencing style.

Comment: @rdhdrhdr: So you're using the bibliography style of the journal you're submitting to and *they* returned it stating that it doesn't conform to *their* style? You're either not doing it right, or ApSS doesn't match what `spr-mp-nameyear-cnd` provides, or you're not submitting it to the appropriate journal you mentioned. I don't know what the style ApSS looks like, hence my working with the source rather than some other guidelines. Perhaps you can ask the editor where you can find a BibTeX style for ApSS.